# Karnaugh map and Circuit of a full adder

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have the following task:

The addition can be implemented by the rules

```
0 + 0 = 0,  0 + 1 = 1,  1 + 0 = 1,  1 + 1 = 10.
```

Full addition requires carry-in and carry-out bits. In general, you must be able to add two terms (bits) a and b, and a carry-in bit Cin to compute a sum bit S and a carry-out bit Cout.

a.)Complete the truth table that describes a full adder: The Boolean function that adds two bits A, B, and a carry-in bit Cin to produce a sum bit S and a carry-out bit Cout.

b.)Using Karnaugh maps find  Boolean expressions that represent the sum function S and the carry-out function Cin.

c.)Draw the circuit of the full adder

I need help with the second and the third part of the question.

Comment: Are you allowed to use xor gates?

Comment: Yes. I am allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two outputs S and Cout so you need to construct a k-map for each of those.

S = f(A,B,Cin)

Cout = g(A, B, Cin)

Our goal is to derive simplified boolean expressions for both the functions f and g. K-maps are quite intuitive once you get the hang of them so I would recommend looking up some examples. Here is a rough idea of how to proceed:

1) label each axis of the table with at most 2 bits and write a separate column/row for each different combination (remember to use gray code).

2) fill in each cell with the corresponding output

3) circle each set of adjacent 1's and derive the boolean expression. This can be found by looking at the at the header and including only the bits that change in the expression.

After you have derived the simplified expressions, constructing the actual circuit can be done directly from the expression.

Comment: For the first part I received the following expression: (~A^~B^Cin)OR(~A^B^~Cin)OR(A^~B^~Cin)OR(A^B^Cin)

Comment: That is correct! Unfortunately K-maps do not allow you to identify more complex boolean operations besides AND, OR, NOT but what you have there is equivalent to A xor B xor Cin.

Comment: Well, they do allow you to identify them, you just need to spot the pattern!

Comment: Ahah, of course it is possible but K-maps don't make it particularly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using Karnaugh maps is a bit of an art, it is particularly
useful when you have only and/or/not. Generally you need to be able to
spot patterns and map these back to the algebraic expression.

Note that while Karnaugh maps are a useful tool for learning, understanding and
writing expressions for a few variables, in digital design one relies on
logic compilers to deal with the actual map of functionality into gates
(and timing, which is important, though functionally irrelevant in this context. However, the gray code aspect in the Karnaugh map arises because of the timing issue).

You can also use a modified Karnaugh map as I will show below.

Here is a Karnaugh map for $S$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c|c} 
C_\text{in} \setminus AB & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
In terms of and/or/not gates this doesn't help since there are none of the usual patterns, so this would require four minterms to represent the 'on'
condition.

If I fix $A=0$ I recognise the xor pattern, and note that I get the
same with $A=1$ (but reversed, because of the Gray coding that people
using in Karnaugh maps).
This suggests $S = \bar{A} (B \oplus C_\text{in}) + A (\overline{B \oplus C_\text{in}})$ which we recognise as $S= A \oplus (B \oplus C_\text{in})$ (order
does't matter here since $\oplus$ is commutative). The circuit for $S$ should
be fairly straightforward to create from this expression.

Another way to recognise this is to draw a Karnaugh map but a 'functional' one: That is, fix $AB$ and place the function of $C_\text{in}$ in the 
corresponding box:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
A \setminus B & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & C_\text{in} & \overline{C_\text{in}} \\ \hline
1 & \overline{C_\text{in}} & C_\text{in} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Here the xor pattern is more obvious, and gives, or course, the same result.

For $C_\text{out}$, the same idea follows (only this time it is a more straightforward use of the Karnaugh map). We have the map for $C_\text{out}$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c|c} 
C_\text{in} \setminus AB & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
You can see the bottom row can be represented by $C_\text{in} (A + B)$ and
the column before the last can be represented by $A B$, so we can write
$C_\text{out} = AB + C_\text{in} (A + B)$, which can be implemented in
a straightforward way.

However, since we already have $A \oplus B$ to compute $S$, we might note
that since the $C_\text{in} AB$ entry is covered by $AB$ the remaining two
terms can be written as $C_\text{in} (A \oplus B)$, which gives
$C_\text{out} = AB + C_\text{in} (A \oplus B)$, thus sharing a gate with
$S$.

So, you see that there isn't (in many cases) a single answer, and that
the Karnaugh map may be useful for spotting patterns, but you need to
eyeball the results and look for further sharing/simplifications.

Note that from a digital design perspective there is typically a tradeoff
between sharing (number of gates) and timing (propagation delay, power)
which the Karnaugh map can't help you with.

Comment: Thank you! I received the same answer by applying a little bit different method which I saw in a youtube video.